# Stop redirecting back to the login page when the app is refreshed or reloaded

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a web based application which the client side is implemented using angularJs. When the browser is refreshed after login into the application, the app again redirects to the login page. It will not stay in the same page where the reload is triggered. Any suggesting solutions would be highly appreciated?

Comment: please show your code.  It is difficult to help if we can't see what it is your code is doing.